# How do I make entered text spill over to the next line but indented in my Android app layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Consider the following layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/post_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/from_picture"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/from_picture"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/from_picture"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject_prompt"
        android:text="@string/subject"
        android:layout_below="@+id/from_picture"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/subject_prompt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/subject_prompt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/from_name"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_prompt"
        android:text="@string/comment_prompt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject_prompt"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/comment_prompt"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/comment_prompt"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The user enters text into the Edittext field labeled "message". If the inputted text is longer than what would fit on the line, it spills over to the next line and continues directly below the first character entered, like so:

[image]

I want it to instead appear over the first character in comment_prompt, like this:

[image]

How can I change the layout to fix this?

Update: Thanks to @Cheticamp's suggestion, I'm a lot closer to a solution:

[image]

I also changed the layout as follows:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_prompt"
        android:text="@string/comment_prompt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject_prompt"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/comment_prompt"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/comment_prompt"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Finally, I put the LeadingMargin code into my RecyclerView adapter onBindViewHolder() method, like so:

```
    int leadingMargin = 107;
    TextView commentText = ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).comment_text;
    LeadingMarginSpan span = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(leadingMargin, 0);
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(item.comment);
    spannableString.setSpan(span, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    commentText.setText(spannableString);
```

Comment: Your are going to need `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` when setting the span; otherwise, you will be able to backspace into the "Comment:" label area. _EditText_ also has some start padding that you will need to address to get the comment label and comment text aligned on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to simply prefix the comment with the comment_prompt. No need for LeadingMargin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [LeadingMarginSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LeadingMarginSpan) in your *EditText*. Something like the following. I have used *ConstraintLayout* for the layout, but you could also use *RelativeLayout*.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Content:"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/message"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/message"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:breakStrategy="balanced"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@null"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Some code that executes after layout can determine how wide the leading margin should be:

```
// Determine the leading margin as the length of the title plus some padding to
// separate the message and the prefix.
int leadingMargin = binding.content.getMeasuredWidth() + 48;
LeadingMarginSpan span = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(leadingMargin, 0);
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor");
spannableString.setSpan(span, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
binding.message.setText(spannableString);
```

[image]

---

---

In response to the updated question:

Your will want to align the left side of the comment text to the left side of the comment prompt. You will also want to eliminate the start margin for the comment text.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/subject_prompt"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/comment_prompt"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/comment_prompt"
    android:breakStrategy="balanced"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

*(Adjust the view's width to what you need it to be.)*

Also, in your code, replace the hard-coded leading margin with some code that will fetch the actual size of the comment prompt. Something like this:

```
int leadingMargin = binding.commentPrompt.getWidth();
```

Of course, get the actual leading margin that you will need after layout has occurred to make sure that you get the actual view width.

Comment: What will happen to a long word starting at the right-hand edge? Will it be carried over intact to the next line or broken into pieces? Also, why wasn't the word "sample" left on the first line? There's enough room for it.

Comment: @FractalBob It's the break strategy at work. Take a look at [android:breakStrategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:breakStrategy).

Comment: Your solution isn't working for me. Here's how I implemented it in my app:                 int leadingMargin = comment.getMeasuredWidth() + 48;
                LeadingMarginSpan span = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(leadingMargin, 0);
                SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(message.getText().toString().trim());
                spannableString.setSpan(span, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                message.setText(spannableString);
                commentsList.add(message.getText().toString().trim());

Comment: It's still not wrapping. leadingMargin has a correct value of 203, since everything has been rendered by this time.

Comment: @FractalBob So, the leading margin is correct and the "Context" text view is properly placed. It's just that the message text view doesn't wrap? If that is the problem, your XML may have an issue. Try the XML I posted without modification in a ConstraintLayout and that should work since it does for me. Note that I have changed the message width to `0dp`. (I see that "Content" should be "Comment", but the code is the same. )

Comment: I'm getting closer to the solution; see my update. If only I could shift all the text to the left...